# TomEE/Tomcat - Run something after deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, deployment, apache-tomee

I have an application, which is packed into a war and then is deployed in TomEE.
We are all happy with this.

But, in this application I have a service, not a web service, is just a servlet which doesn't give any response, just has the purpose to do some things, like starting a jobs scheduler. For the moment I start this jobs scheduler via an ant task, which makes a call to a class that makes the call to that service.

What is my concern?

I want to start this jobs scheduler right after deployment of my application finished, be careful, not while deploying, but **after deploying**, because if it is while deploying process, guess what, I want to call something that isn't deployed yet, and *voila*, deadly 404.

What have I tried?

- TomEE/Tomcat context listeners - these are executed while deploying process;
- Servlet implementations with load-on-startup tag and also I was sure that my servlet was the last executed servlet - these are also executed while deploying process;
- The methods presented above but with some inner-threads which I tried to put on sleep in order to let TomEE to finish his deployment process, but seems that these inner-threads put TomEE in sleep too.

So, if you could help me with a suggestion how to start something after deploying an application, I'll be very grateful to you.

Thank you,
Andrei

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing when you get '404'. Are you running something on the server on startup which is acting as a client and calling another Servlet?

Comment: @SiKelly Actually, those two parts which you referred (client and 'another Servlet') are in the same application, the one that I want to deploy it. In this application I have a bunch of servlets, and one of these is built to respond only to a specific http call. I want a solution which allows me to execute a servlet init method (or something like that) and in this method to make the call to that specific http link. But this call has to be done only after the deploying is done, because if it isn't, the servlet that respond to that specific link, isn't available too.

Comment: This makes even less sense! If the Servlet that will make the call and the Servlet that will handle it are in the same application - why are you making an HTTP call? Why not just a simple method call?

Comment: Ok, the problem was resolved exactly with a method call, you're right. But as I wrote in the end of my next post, could be very interesting to find a way in which you can do an action after the deploying of an application finished on TomEE/Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I'll describe what I've done in order to resolve my problem, but is just a workaround, in my opinion.

As I've said on the first post, I have a bunch of servlets and one of them is built to act just on a specific call.

Let me add more details.

In my application, also I have a spring-framework context.
With this in mind, I have a `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` which is mapped on an url pattern like "*.srv" (srv from service), and  handles some http calls, like "start", "stop", "status", all these operations being related to my jobs scheduler.

My question was "how to make a call to one of these methods (eg: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/start.srv`) **after deployment**?". 
After some research, I've found that the tomcat last deployed element is http context, so if I try to configure a servlet init method to call a service through a http call which should be offered by the application which is not deployed yet, I get a 404 (this is logic, because http context is deployed the last, and http calls couldn't be made).

After reading that, I followed another path (to a workaround), and I've get some help from here

http://sujitpal.blogspot.ro/2007/03/accessing-spring-beans-from-legacy-code.html

and I've accesed the bean which handle the "start", "stop" and "status" requests (the bean which in normal conditions is called only via a http call).

But, this question is still opened. Still I want to know if it is a way to configure tomcat to run something after a deploying process.

If I wasn't clear enough please let me know.

Have a nice day,
Andrei